# Cannot resolve keyword into field. Choices are following, in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have the following models, `models.py`

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    ratings = models.FloatField(default=1000)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

class Match(models.Model):

    match_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    totalPlayers = models.IntegerField(default=2)
    winner = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-match_time']

class Participant(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player_points = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

What I want is basically to write a Query that can return me the following things, `Player_Name`, `Total Matches by Player`, `Total Points of Player`, `Matches Won by the Player`, `Player Ratings`

I wrote a query like this and it worked great for all the columns above, except `Total Points of Player` and `Matches Won by the Player`

```
players = Account.objects.annotate(matches=Count('participant')).order_by('-ratings')
```

So, following the same principle, I tried the following Query to get what I needed exactly,

```
players = Account.objects.annotate(matches=Count('participant'), total_points=Count('player_points'), matches_won=Count('winner')).order_by('-ratings')
```

But this is giving me the following error,

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'player_points' into field. Choices are: date_joined, id, match, matches, name, participant, phone, profile_pic, ratings, user, user_id
```

I unfortunately do not understand how I can get my required result. Can anyone help me reach what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `player_points` are not in the account model, it is in the participant.

```
players = Account.objects.annotate(matches=Count('participant'), total_points=Count('player_points'), matches_won=Count('winner')).order_by('-ratings')
```

For the `Total Points of Player` use this in the annotate.

```
total_points=Sum('participant__player_points') # By the description i think you are looking the Sum of the point as a total not the Count, but you can change it if not.
```

For the `Matches Won by the Player`:

```
mathces_won=Count('match')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Total Points of players worked like a charm, however matches won are not working. The returned result actually is counting the total number of matches played by that player (so the matches player has played, the result is same as the matches won by him). **What I am trying that the query should compare the player with match__winner and if they are equal, then add 1 to the Matches Won**

Comment: @AsadHussain since the Match has a ForeignKey to Account when you Count('match') will show the number of Mathes that has as winner that account.  If the number returned by Count('match') and Count('participant'), can be that the Account has won all the matches he played. Can you check if this is the case?

Comment: No, that's not the case. For all accounts, it is returning the same value in `Matches Won` as the value in `Matches Played` (which can't/isn't true)

Comment: I also tried to use `Count("match__winner")` but it gave the same results.

Comment: @AsadHussain please add `distinct=True` to the Count statement. Count('match', distinct=True), matches=Count('participant', distinct=True)

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm! Although I don't understand how by adding distinct did this work lol. But thank you very much for the help! I will try to figure it out myself that how did it work